# NumberFormat: parse() vs parseObject()

Tags: java, io, numbers

When would it be the case to use `parseObject()` rather than `parse()`?
I am aware that the first returns an Object and the second a Number, however when is the case of parsing an object different from a `Number` hence justifying the presence of `parseObject()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you're dealing with a `NumberFormat`, there's probably no good reason to. However, if you're in the unusual situation of only knowing about [`Format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html), then you don't know what kind of value you're parsing to, and `parseObject` is all there is.

Personally I don't remember ever using just plain `Format` on its own, but I suppose if you're in the general "parsing and formatting" business (e.g. for UI widgets) then it could be useful.

Comment: 1 example of parseObject() without returning a Number?

Comment: @Rollerball: Sure - if you don't know that it's a NumberFormat, and it might be a DateFormat...